# How to delete a Virtual Machine from Hyper-V Failover Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, failovercluster

I have a Hyper-V 2008 R2 failover cluster with 3 nodes. I added new 3 Virtual Machines to the failover clusters, one of them failed with errors:

```
Event ID: 1069
Cluster resource 'Virtual Machine Configuration [server]' in clustered service or application '[server] failed.
```

and

```
Event ID: 21502
'Virtual Machine Configuration [server]' failed to register the virtual machine with the virtual machine management service.
```

I can't bring the resource online at all. I see I can right click on the resource and choose "delete." I just wanted to make sure that would be deleting it only from the Failover Cluster and not from Hyper-V Manager.

How do I delete the failed virtual server from the Failover Cluster Manager and retain the virtual machine in the Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: I don't have a Windows Server 2008 R2 failover cluster to check at the moment but deleting the VM from Failover Cluster Manager should remove it as a clustered role/service but leave the VM intact. It should be the equivalent to the `Remove` option in a Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster. As a precaution, create a dummy VM, cluster it, then delete it from the cluster and see what happens.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yeah, that looks to be the ticket. I wanted to double check. Got to love test servers! Add the answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a Windows Server 2008 R2 failover cluster to check at the moment but deleting the VM from Failover Cluster Manager should remove it as a clustered role/service but leave the VM intact. It should be the equivalent to the Remove option in a Windows Server 2012 Failover Cluster.

Comment: Deleting from failover cluster manager does turn the VM into a normal non-HA VM which you can manage from hyper-v manager on whichever cluster node it was left on.  You can then bring it back into cluster manager to make it HA again.

Comment: Looks like the root of the issue of setting this up correctly was the snapshot file was set to a path that was not on the storage cluster. I moved it to match all the other servers and was able to get this working correctly. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help and glad you got it resolved.